# Multiple Popconfirm button displayed on single button click

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have created an table using ant design table component in which the last column contains buttons for edit and deleting the table row items. I have added a popconfirm component from antd whenever someone tries to delete a row. But whats causing me trouble is whenever i try to delete a row by clicking the delete button, all the popconfirms from other rows are also get shown.[Multiple popconfirms on single click of delete button of a specific row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSgLk.png)

The code for my button item is such:

```
{
            title: 'Actions',
            dataIndex: 'actions',
            key: 'actions',
            render: (_, record) => {

                // console.log("Record", record.id)

                const onEdit = () => {
                    console.log("Record", record.id)
                    setRecordId(record.id);

                    // console.log("Record on edit button", record)
                    setIsModalVisible(true)
                    setAddRecordData(record)
                    setTitle("Edit")

                }


                const onDelete = () => {
                    setVisible(true)
                    console.log("Record on delete button", record)
                }

                const handleOk = async () => {
                    const id = record.id;
                    const response = await props.callExpertiseApiDel(id)
                    console.log("delete response:", response)

                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        setVisible(false)
                        async function fetchData() {
                            await props.callExpertiseApi();
                        }
                        fetchData();
                    }
                };

                const handleCancel = () => {
                    console.log('Clicked cancel button', record.id);
                    setVisible(false);
                    setAddRecordData({})
                }

                return <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    <Icondescription icon={<EditOutlined />} label='Edit'
                        className='action-edit-icon' btnClick={onEdit} />

                    <Popconfirm
                        title="Are you sure to delete this item?"
                        visible={visible}
                        onConfirm={handleOk}
                        onCancel={handleCancel}
                    >
                        <Icondescription icon={<DeleteOutlined />} btnClick={onDelete} />
                    </Popconfirm>

                </div>
            }
```

How do i get rid of this multiple popconfirm on single click of a delete key?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have one state `visible` for each of you row. You can move your render to a separate component and use local state there inside component. Or you can leave your render function but store in your state all visible flags like this:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState({})

// then where you want to set

setVisible((prevVisible) => ({
  ...prevVisible,
  [record.id]: true
}))
```